# LL1 grammar hidden ambiguity

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar

I've been trying to generate a parser table for the following grammar:

> S-> LP ; E
>
> LP-> LP ; num | num
>
> E-> num | var | fun ( E )

The need to eliminate left-recursion is evident, so it ends up:

> S-> LP ; E
>
> LP-> num LP'
>
> LP'-> ; num LP' | λ
>
> E-> num | var | fun ( E )

The problem comes when finding firsts and follows for LP and LP', where:

> First(LP)=  num
>
> Follow(LP)= ;
>
> First(LP') = ; λ
>
> Follow(LP') = ;

Since LP' has λ as a first, that means during the creation of the parsing table the productions that would take me from LP' to ; are:

> LP'-> ; num LP'
>
> LP'-> λ

Thus creating ambiguity. Is there any way to solve this problem? I've looked into previous questions and eliminating λ was mentioned but I haven't been able to do so in a way that eliminates ambiguity.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.